# HTML5 Game running in a webview usin Adobe AIR for iPhone/Android

Tags: html, air

Currently we are developing a game which will have access to a small suite of html5 based side games such as slots or a scratcher game. My question is can these games that have already been built in html5, be embedded into an app created using Adobe AIR(in FLASH) for iPhone and Android?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not!

If you are just trying to port the games to Andriod though you could simply run them in a WebView, or use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).